# Wildcard in XQuery corresponding to [where LIKE '%.mp3'] in SQL

Tags: xml, xquery, where-clause, wildcard, flwor

I´m wondering how to use wildcards in XQuery.

I have two lines of codes which gives me the return that I want from a xml file:

```
for $phrase in //phrases[@pPhrase="Phrase1.mp3"]
return concat(string($phrase/@pPhrase), ", ",$phrase/ancestor::entrance/string(@name))
```

The problem I have is that sometimes I don´t know the exact name of the mp3 file I´m looking for.
So, if this would be a SQL query I´d type:
`where pPhrase LIKE '%.mp3'`.

```
for $phrase in //phrases[@pPhrase LIKE ='%.mp3']
```

The above line doesn´t work of course, so what is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 3):

You could use

```
//phrases[contains(@pPhrase,'.mp3']
```

Or to be more precise (since xPath 2.0)

```
//phrases[ends-with(@pPhrase,'.mp3']
```

Comment: And more generally, you can use the matches() function with regular expression support.